# How do i add multiple values to a database using flask and SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have watched some tutorials on flask lately, and I have ended up with this:

the controller:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, url_for, request, 
redirect
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///userinfo.db'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class userinfo(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    epost = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    nøkkelord = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Email %r>' % self.id


@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template("home.html", title = "homepage")

@app.route('/newscraper', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def newscraper():

    email = None
    keywords = None

    if request.method == "POST":
        email = request.form["email"]
        new_email = userinfo(epost=email)
        try:
            db.session.add(new_email)
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect('/newscraper')
        except:
            return "Ops! her skjedde det en feil1."

        keywords = request.form["keywords"]
        new_keywords = userinfo(nøkkelord=keywords)
        try:
            db.session.add(new_keywords)
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect('/newscraper')
        except:
            return "Ops! her skjedde det en feil2."

        return redirect('/newscraper')

    else:

        return render_template("newscraper.html", title = " newscraper")



@app.route('/form', methods=["POST"])
def form():
    return render_template("form.html", title = "newscraper")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

and the html document, newscraper:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}


{% block content %}
  <div class="container">
    <h1>newscraper</h1>
    <br><br/>

  <form action="/form" method="POST">
    <div class="mb-3">
      <label for="emailInput" class="form-label">Epost adresse</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="emailInput" placeholder="name@example.com" name='email'>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
      <label for="keywordsInput" class="form-label">Nøkkelord separert med ","</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="keywordsInput" rows="3" placeholder="strømpris, vindmøller, jakt.." name='keywords'></textarea>
    </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

The userinfo.db file exists and is located within the some directory.

However, when I try to add values to epost and nøkkelord, they don't appear in the database. (I have a SQLite browser to view it with) I am fairly new to flask and HTML, but at the same time, I've followed multiple tutorials without luck.

Answer (score 0):

You should create the database, add create_all() to your code after the class definition.
I also noticed that in your code that you are adding two records and not one. if this is your intention, fine, otherwise do this:

```
uinfo = userinfo(nøkkelord=keywords, epost=email)
db.session.add(uinfo)
db.session.commit()
```

to create the database and tables:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///userinfo.db'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class userinfo(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    epost = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    nøkkelord = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Email %r>' % self.id

# Create The Database and the tables
with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()
```

I hope this helps